# Identifying neutral for new switch with night light

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch

I am trying to replace a single pole switch with one that has a built in night light. The new switch requires a neutral for the night light to function.

Based on the previous wiring, it seems pretty clear the line / load, and I'd have to assume the bundle in the back is neutral, given it is not used by either of the switches.

The coloring is kind of confusing to me though, since it is a combo of black and white spliced together. The line appears to be white as well. [image]Is my understanding correct?

Here's a closer look

[image]

Photos where wires enter:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just because you need neutral, doesn't mean it's there. Half of all switches are wired as "switch loops" - if you see white to a plain switch it's probably a switch loop and no neutral is available.   This wiring looks very strange. It may have been miswired.

Comment: What is the right hand thing with all the black tape around it?  Wiring almost makes some sense if it is an outlet.  Not much more sense.

Comment: Both black boxes in the picture are switches. If this is a switch loop it would be strange because these switches control the light and fan in a very small bathroom; there would be no need for a 3 way. Is there a way to test? There is an outlet close by so perhaps that's where the unused bundle leads.

Comment: That might be neutral, but neutral cannot be black, can only be white(or grey).  To do it right some wires will need to be switched around at both ends(light and switch).  The whites carrying power will need black/red tape/marking on them.  This is just a guess so do not go switching wires till you know what is what.

Comment: Or maybe they did a switched neutral? Could I use a multimeter to figure it out?

Comment: With a meter neutral to ground should be 0 volts.  Hot/switched hot should be 120 volts to neutral or ground.  If using conduit, box should be ground(no ground wires showing).  Wires on switches are hot and switched hot(should be).

Comment: Can you post a photo showing clearly where the wires enter the box at?

Comment: Added another photo, I'm pretty sure it's a switched neutral. The contact tester only lights up on the load wire when the switch for the fan is on. The light switch (lower voltage) doesn't light up regardless of on/off. The bundle in the back always lights with the tester.

Comment: Just a note that the upper right cable entry seems to have the wrong fitting. For an armored-type cable (e.g. MC), the fitting needs a wall/stop around the inside of its opening to stop the outer metal armor from entering and possibly abrading a conductor. You can see a strip of the armor coming in and bending around/on the black conductor. The upper left (and bottom right) cable entry has the correct type of fitting, blocking the outside armor and allowing only the conductor inside.

Comment: Contact testers are less than completely reliable.An actual multimeter would give you a much more reliable answer.

Comment: ... Someone want to turn the comments into a "how to determine this yourself, or at least how to get the data we need to answer it" Answer?

Comment: Sanity check: is the photo showing as you found it, or after you had started changing it? What make/model is the device on the left?

Comment: That was as I found it. After a bunch of testing it turns out the top right is the hot and neutral feed. The top left and bottom right were switched neutrals. It was easy enough to fix.